# Jquery hover function cursor hover where it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, hover, onmouseover

In the eg below you can see that when I'm hovering the image the black box bounce.

I want to be able to hover only the Black box. 
I can't understand what I'm missing.

Also, I want to add some CSS3 on the black box when is on top hovered. to do this I'm adding a class .focus but seems to not working.
Any suggestion?
Ta,

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Czh/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the *hover* event on the `<li>` element, not only on the `<a>` (the black box), so it is triggered when you hover any element within the list element.

Change you code to this:

```
// bind hover on the anchor element
$("#nav-shadow li a").hover(function() {
    var e = this;
    // remove the .find('a') as 'e' is the anchor
    $(e).stop().animate({
        ...
    }, 250, function() {
        ...
    });
    // use .sibling() instead of .find('img')
    $(e).siblings("img.width320").stop().animate({
        ...
    }, 250);
}, function() {
        ...
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/X9dwm/)**

For the second part, I have no clue what you're trying to explain... :-/

Comment: thank you so much works perfectly. I need to give a focus class when the black box is hovered on margin-top: -14px;

Comment: The class "focus" is correctly added to the anchor (i've added some CSS for you to see)

Comment: sure, I won't but did you get what I want to do?

Comment: Add a class "focus" to the anchor after the animation ? It is doing that already.

Comment: Yes it adds the class to the anchor. Check the fiddle, i have added a class `#nav-shadow li a.focus` that sets a yellow border. When you hover the black box, it adds the border when the animation finishes. Now do you want it to be added as soon as the box is hovered ?

Comment: Yes indeed. You were missing a .removeClass() in the case the width is > 765 (this is your code afterall - you could have find it out yourself).